# What's the actual type of lambda in C#?

Tags: c#, lambda, func

I read that C# lambdas can be imlicitly converted to Action or Func , but lambda cannot be executed directly [Define a lambda function and execute it immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220442/define-a-lambda-function-and-execute-it-immediately)
For example :

```
int n = (()=>5)(); //doesn't work
int n = ((Func<int>)(()=>5))(); //works
```

So what is the actual type of lambda and why it cannot be directly called? Is it because C# type system is "weaker" than Haskell or Scala one?

Comment: The answer in the linked question is valid for your question. C# compiler needs to know context, which is either assignment or casting. In the first sample you do neither

Comment: The type system is not related to this. `Dim n = Function() 5` works just fine in VB.NET, and it's similar in F#, and they have the same underlying type system. This is just an issue with C#.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer no F# and C# doesn't have the same "type system" . Why? Because 5.0+5 is incorrect in F#, but is still correct in C#.

Comment: @ig-melnyk that's a feature of the language, not of the type system.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer and this "feature" is called "type system" - how types "work" together.

Comment: @ig-melnyk language != type system , but whatever, honestly I'm not interesting in discussing this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A lambda expression doesn't have a type. It cannot, because any type in the .NET world that it could have, would also hard-code the type of the lambda's parameters and result. Now consider:

```
x => x + 1
```

What type could `x` have? What type will the result be? There isn't any single answer, and the lambda expression can indeed be converted to `Func<int, int>`, `Func<double, double>`, and many other delegate types with different parameters. Giving a lambda expression a type would disallow such expressions. C# did want to allow such expressions, so was designed not to give such expressions any type.

Comment: well explained, if a code example be given, i am instersted

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of code example you have in mind, all I can think to add is examples of delegate types the expression could be converted to, which I've now included in the answer.

Comment: It makes sense. I have just tested this in F# and Haskell. In F# in works only for "int" - the reason is that F# doesn't use implicit conversions. In the case of C# - compiler really can't "know" the type, so you are right.

Comment: @ig-melnyk What about `x => x + x`? This would not use any conversion from `int` to `double`.

Comment: I thought it can create in the compile-time different functions for example : (x=>x+x)(5) : Func<int,int> because we called this function with an int argument .By the way, I accepted your answer because it really answers my question

Comment: @ig-melnyk Even if that did implicitly convert the lambda expression to `Func<int,int>` in an extended C#, wouldn't the lambda expression itself still not have any type?

Comment: As a further example, in `static List<string> AppendOnes(List<string> li) { return li.ConvertAll(x => x + 1); }` the arrow becomes an instance of `System.Converter<string, string>`. Historically, the generic delegate `Converter<,>` existed before the BCL had "funcs", i.e. the type family `Func<>`, `Func<,>`, `Func<,,>`, etc.

Comment: My IDE (ReSomething ;-) ) mostly uses `Action` in the simplest lambda case.

Answer (score 9):

This is because `() => 5` can be compatible with various delegate types (e.g. you may have a custom `delegate` that takes nothing and returns `int`). And in order to create a `delegate`, compiler has to know the exact type. It can't just pick a random type that suits your needs. So that's why unless you cast it to an actual delegate type, you can't `Invoke` it.

In cases like where a method expects a `delegate`, that conversion is implicitly done by the compiler:

```
void Foo(Func<int> func) {  }

Foo(() => 5);
```

And it is also important to know that `delegates` are actually classes behind the scenes. And each time you create a `delegate` instance, compiler creates an instance of that `class`. So either way you have to specify a type so the compiler will know which type to use.

Comment: when we put ``()=>`` in ``Select()`` or ``Where()`` what it means ? please explain

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I was just adding that to the answer :)